# c++ lambda funtion issue

Tags: c++, lambda

Calling only inside a method requires, so I made it a lambda function, not a class member.

The method below has been converted to lambda.

I seem to misunderstand lambda's reference capture, what's wrong?

```
A::Convert(std::string in_, std::string &out_) {
    out_.substr(in_,0,3);
} 

A::Start() {
    std::string buffer = "1123456";
    std::string out;
    Convert(buffer,out); 
    std::cout << out ;// result : 112
}
```

==> convert lambda

```
A::Start() {
    std::string buffer = "1123456";
    std::string out;
    auto Convert = [&](std::string in_, std::string out_) {
        out_.substr(in_,0,3);
    };
    Convert(buffer, out); 
    std::cout << out ;// result : empty!!!!!
}
```

Comment: your lambda passes `out_` by value not by reference, so it is destroyed when you leave lamda scope

Comment: You never use the captured reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending copy of `out` to lambda. so `out_` inside lambda is not the one you defined outside.

This should work :

```
std::string buffer = "1123456";
std::string out;
auto Convert = [](std::string in_, std::string & out_) {
    out_=in_.substr(0,3);
};
Convert(buffer, out);
```

or

```
 std::string buffer = "1123456";
 std::string out;
 auto Convert = [&out](std::string in_) {
    out =in_.substr(0,3);
 };
    Convert(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the captured `out` with the by value passed parameter `out_`:

```
auto Convert = [&](std::string in_, std::string out_) {
    out_.substr(in_,0,3);
};
```

The lambda does not do anything with the captured `out` but creates a substring of `out_`. Moreover you forgot to return something or store the substring somewhere.

Use either captures or parameters not both and return something:

```
auto Convert = [&]() {
    return out.substr(buffer,0,3);
};
out = Convert(buffer, out);
```

or assign directly:

```
auto Convert = [&]() {
    out = out.substr(buffer,0,3);
};
Convert();
```

or shorter:

```
auto Convert = [&]() {
    out = out.substr(buffer,0,3);
}();
//^^   immediately call the lambda
```

Answer (score 0):

The "out" in your "main" function is covered by the local variable "out" in your "lambda" function, so you are assigning a value to the "lambda" function parameter "out", but not to the "out" in the main function, so the output is empty. You can change the name of the parameter in the "lambda" function, and there will be no problem.